# Size the background color using

Tags: html, css, background, background-color

I'm trying to scale the background color. I'm having the nav bar and I want the color to be from the nav bar to the bottom.

I've tried using:

```
background-size: 80px 60px;
```

Which doesn't work because it is still filling the page for 100%. Also for everyone to know i'm using bootstrap.

This is the css from bootstrap:

```
body {
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    color: #333;
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
}
```

These are my css rules which override the bootstrap css files.

```
body {
    background-size: 80px 60px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

The nav bar is allways has a margin of 15% left and right so the width that the bg color has to be is 70%. The top margin is 0 because that it is following the image at the top.

If i've forgot to give information my apalogies and I will add the needed information asap.

Comment: `background-size` only works for images: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size.

Comment: and gradients.. check my answer

Comment: Your may also find interesting the background-clip alternative, depending on the effect you want http://css-tricks.com/transparent-borders-with-background-clip/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cannot size a background-color, but you can give a specific size to a gradient which is treated as a background-image.

here's what you could do:
http://jsfiddle.net/JkhCs/

```
body {
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    color: #333;
    background-color:transparent;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(red, red);
    background-image: linear-gradient(red, red);
    background-size:80px 80px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Is there also a way to align this to the middle? Or adjust the margin left and right?

Comment: sure, with background-position: your values;

Comment: I'm trying this: background-size:70% 100%; But the 100% doesn't seem to work right because it doesn't fill it from top to bottom. I can use 10000px but that's not a neat way to do it.

Comment: Thank you very much for the effort taken

Answer (score -2):

Do you know `backgroud-size:cover` and `backgroud-size:contain`?

Check it out at [css3.info](http://www.css3.info/preview/background-size/) or [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp), it’s fantabulous.

Comment: I’m very well aware of “W3Fools”, but it’s stupid to condemn anything flat. “W3Fools” never helped me with anything, “W3Schools” did. Can you tell what’s wrong with this particular reference?